# Restart browser Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

I'm doing a test where I have to activate some Chrome's feature. After doing that I have to restart the browser (if I don't do it this feature will not be activated).

How can I do that with Selenium ?

I have already tried with closing and opening a new instance but it doesn't work. The feature I want to activate is the NPAPI (chrome://flags/#enable-npapi) available into the chrome version I'm using.

I'm using the 2.7 version of Python.

Comment: Note : NPAPI is deprecated since 2015.

Comment: As I said, I'm using a version of Chrome that allows me to use it (43)

Comment: Available isn't incompatible with deprecated

Comment: Did you try creating instances of Chrome of a specific user? i.e. `pathToChromeData\User Data\Default`

Comment: I've not tried, could you please give me an example of it ?